# *** TypeError: Expected float32 passed to parameter 'y' of op 'Equal', got 'auto' of type 'str' instead

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, autoencoder

I am playing around with a keras.io example where a Variational Autoencoder is build, which can be found here: https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/#variational-autoencoder

1. There I am trying to replace the binary_crossentropy-loss with a MeanSquaredError-loss but I am getting a TypeError. What do I have to do, to get it run?

   ```
        # reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=(1, 2)))
        reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(data, reconstruction), axis=(1, 2)))
   ```

Error message:

> TypeError: Expected float32 passed to parameter 'y' of op 'Equal', got 'auto' of type 'str' instead. Error: Expected float32, got 'auto' of type 'str' instead.

2. Furthermore I don't understand why a binary_crossentropy-loss is used, because  I understood this loss as an classification-loss but here I am comparing the values of my original data with its reconstruction, which is rather something like a regression rather than a classification. So, why is it still appropriate to use the crossentropy-loss?
3. When I am running the code with the crossentropy-loss and looking on my losses, then the KL-loss and the reconstruction-loss do not sum up to the total-loss. I mean the total-loss is always unequal to the sum out of KL-loss and reconstruction-loss, although in the train_step-method it is correctly programmed. So, why is there a deviation?

Comment: Can you provide the part of the code which generated the error and the whole error output? That would make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning 3.: There is a deviation because each loss is averaged over all samples within a batch. If each sample is considered, than the reconstruction_loss and the KL_loss do sum up to the total_loss

Concerning 1.: I think, that the `tf.reduce_sum` command is not correct, because it is summing up all pixel losses. I think it should be rather `tf.reduce_mean`, which takes the average loss over all pixels. I think it is important in order to have the reconstruction_loss in balance to the KL_loss. This unfortuntley leed to bad training results, which I interpret as "posterior collapse" (still not sure, if this is really posterior collapse). The following plot shows the bad distributed latent space. For further explanation see: https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/#variational-autoencoder

[[image: latent space plot - for further explanation see https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/#variational-autoencoder ][1]]

A solution that I have found is to weight the losses differently like this:

```
total_loss = 1000*reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
```

This led to correct results:

[image]

Are my interpretations about taking the mean rather than the sum and about the posterior collapse correct? Is it approxpriate to weight my losses?